# How to know what changes I did on a specific branch?

Tags: git, version-control

You reading this obviously you know about git, but I have a different question. How to know that what changes I made in a specific branch? e.g. I have a branch called **dev** and I had made some changes but I don't remember them. I will explain more. As you know Branches don't have physical existence(I mean something like folders). That's why it's hard to know/find out what was the recent changes. Maybe to create a folder called **dev** for **branch dev**. My question is something related to experience, so it's not a beginner question. How to know/find them? Give me your idea about this or give some examples.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the `git log` or `git diff` commands or a graphical repository browser?

Comment: Exercise: suppose you fixed a bug in commit `feedb0g`, last week or so. *Why do you care which branches contain this commit?* (Sometimes you do care; enumerate the times when you do care.) Which is more important: the names of the containing branches, or the raw hash ID, `feedb0g`? Will `git log --all -S` or `git log --all -G` let you find the commit hash ID quickly? If you have the hash ID, what does `git branch --contains <hash>` show?

Comment: @torek really helpful thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As you know Branches don't have physical existence

Branches actually do have a "physical existence" (or at least what amounts to one for the digital medium we are talking about). Each branch is stored as a file under `.git/refs/heads`.

> That's why it's hard to know/find out what was the recent changes.

Finding recent changes isn't hard at all. You can use `git log` to view the history of the current branch. It has many flags that you can see with `git help log`. My usual usage is `git log --oneline --graph` which shows a good visualization of the history of the current branch.

Additionally, `git diff` will show actual lines that were changed. For example, `git diff HEAD~` shows the changes from the previous commit and `git diff master` shows the changes in the entire branch. Again, you can see more information with `git help diff`.

To learn more about the basic commands that are available, I suggest that you read the first three chapters in [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). This book goes in great detail about how to use git and how it works under the hoods. The firsts few chapters gives a good overview of the commands you will use most often.

Comment: Be aware that ref-names can become *packed* (written into a flat-text file, `.git/packed-refs`); this normally deletes their unpacked equivalent files. Those files get re-created if the ref is updated. This means that if a ref exists in *both forms*, the `.git/refs/` entry takes precedence and the flat-file entry is ignored. There is, in progress (has been for a year plus I think), an ongoing attempt to put in a real database for ref-names, instead of these simple flat-file-and-directory methods. When that happens you won't want to rely on `.git/refs/` at all.

Comment: @torek Thanks for the additional details. My primary purpose of pointing out `.git/refs` is to refute the OP's misunderstanding that "branches don't have physical existence". They are in fact stored somewhere. Whether that's directly in the file system or in some database, they still have a "physical existence". Of course, my interpretation "physical existence" might differ from the OP's. There is likely a deeper misunderstanding here about what a branch actually is.

Answer (score 2):

If you are connected to the dev branch, you could run a "git diff" command that would list the differences between the dev branch and the last version of dev branch you pushed to the repo.